# Displaying values of multiple checkboxes from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox, explode

I have a form that uses several checkbox fields to save profile data.

The values are being submitted to the database like `1, 2` courtesy of imploding the `$_POST` variable but I can't seem to figure out how explode them on a profile page and display the values.

**My submit code (part of the insert query);**

```
$profile_piercings = implode(", ", $_POST['profile_piercings']);
```

**My profile code to echo out the values;**

```
<?php if(!empty($profile['profile_piercings'])){ ?>
<dt>Piercings</dt>
<dd><?php //echo $profile['profile_piercings'] ?>
<?php 
$piercing_values = $profile['PiercingsText'];
$piercings = explode(", ", $piercing_values);
echo $piercing_values; ?></dd>
<?php } ?>
```

When printing the exploded array, it looks as though my query has only passed the first value. I need to do it this way to translate a numeric value into the corresponding text value (eg 1 = ears).

An extract of my SQL code;

```
frmhaircolour.id,
                frmhaircolour.textvalue AS HairColourText,
                frmpiercings.id,
                frmpiercings.textvalue AS PiercingsText,
FROM profiles
            LEFT JOIN frmeyecolour ON profiles.profile_eyecolour = frmeyecolour.id
            LEFT JOIN frmhaircolour ON profiles.profile_haircolour = frmhaircolour.id
            LEFT JOIN frmpiercings ON profiles.profile_piercings = frmpiercings.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through on your array:

```
$piercings = explode(", ", $piercing_values);
foreach ($piercings as $piercing) {
   echo $piercing."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I printed out the piercings array but it looks as though my query is only passing the first value in the column - I've updated my question with an extract of my sql query.

Answer (score 0):

For getting all values use `foreach`:

```
$piercings = explode(", ", $piercing_values);
foreach ($piercings as $piercing) {
   echo $piercing."<br>";
}
```

And for getting specific values :

```
$piercings = explode(", ", $piercing_values);
echo $piercing[0]."<br>"; // or $piercing[1]; depending on what you want.
```

Comment: Thanks. I printed out the piercings array but it looks as though my query is only passing the first value in the column - I've updated my question with an extract of my sql query.